# SAS Viya cannot accept ldap users more than 500

Tags: linux, sas, ldap, openldap

I am running SAS Viya and let it add its new users from ldap (on linux).

However, if ldap users were created more than the number of 500, SAS Viya cannot accept ldap users which have created from the 501st.

Also, when I execute 'ldapsearch' command on linux, it returns the information of ldap users upto 500 entries as maximum and doesn't show info of ldap users from 501st with an error message 'size limit exceeded (4)'.

I have read this url (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4526411) to solve the Error 'size limit exceeded (4)'. However, I don't know the location of the files required to change and don't know how to use 'ldapmodify'.

I don't know anything about ldap so neither dont know what to check for solving this problem.

I need your help so bad. Help me Pleas

Thanks.

Comment: Open a ticket with SAS support.  You are paying them to be able to use VIYA, let them explain how to fix the issue.

Comment: We have over 6000 user imported from LDAP in a VIYA3.5 environment. I would rather look into your ldap installation than your SAS VIYA

Comment: I had opened a track with sas supports already but they said the problem is about Ldap not them. And that was the end of their supports.

Comment: How do I check the ldap installation? What files in which location should I refer?